# Import svg filter for webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, sass, bundling-and-minification, snowpack

I have a react project which used an svg filter for rendering:

```css
@use 'sass:math';
@import '../Theme.scss';

$borderW: 5px;
$borderR: 5px;
$numOfBlobs: 4;

.blob-btn {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 46px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: $borderR;
  color: $primary;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: $borderW solid $primary;
    border-radius: $borderR;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    left: $borderW * 1.5;
    top: $borderW * 1.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    transition: all 0.3s 0.2s;
    border-radius: $borderR;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: $borderR;

    &:after {
      transition: all 0.3s;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      border-radius: $borderR;
    }
  }

  &__inner {
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: $borderR;
    background: #ffffff;
  }

  // additional container created, because in FF blobs are breaking overflow:hidden of element with svg gooey filter
  &__blobs {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    filter: url('#goo');
  }

  &__blob {
    position: absolute;
    top: $borderW;
    width: math.div(100%, $numOfBlobs);
    height: 100%;
    background: $primary;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(0, 150%, 0) scale(1.7);
    transition: transform 0.45s;

    @supports (filter: url('#goo')) {
      transform: translate3d(0, 150%, 0) scale(1.4);
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $numOfBlobs {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        left: ($i - 1) * math.div(120%, $numOfBlobs);
        transition-delay: ($i - 1) * 0.08s;
      }
    }

    .blob-btn:hover & {
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.7);

      @supports (filter: url('#goo')) {
        transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.4);
      }
    }
  }
}

.blob-btn-secondary {
  @extend .blob-btn;

  color: $secondary;
  &:before {
    border: $borderW solid $secondary;
  }
}
```

```html
  <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
      >
        <defs>
          <filter id="goo">
            <feGaussianBlur
              in="SourceGraphic"
              result="blur"
              stdDeviation="10"
            ></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix
              in="blur"
              mode="matrix"
              values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 21 -7"
              result="goo"
            ></feColorMatrix>
            <feBlend in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix"></feBlend>
          </filter>
        </defs>
      </svg>
      <button
        class='blob-btn'}
        style={{
          padding: '15px',
          margin: '15px',
          width: '100%',
          zIndex: 10,
          filter: isHovered ? 'blur(2px)' : 'none',
          // color: color,
        }}
      >
      Coming Soon
        <span className="blob-btn__inner">
          <span className="blob-btn__blobs" style={{ filter: `url(#goo)` }}>
            <span
              className="blob-btn__blob"
              style={{ background: color }}
            ></span>
            <span
              className="blob-btn__blob"
              style={{ background: color }}
            ></span>
            <span
              className="blob-btn__blob"
              style={{ background: color }}
            ></span>
            <span
              className="blob-btn__blob"
              style={{ background: color }}
            ></span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </button>
```

It works well when running withing snopack, but as soon as I try to bundle it looses the connection to goo svg. Trying with webpack, as well as the native snowpack bundler I get:

> [16:56:29] [snowpack] Build failed with 1 error:
> build/dist/components/PositionAwareButton.css:10837:14: error: Could
> not resolve "/dist/components/#goo"

Any pointers on where I need to start looking are highly appreciated